# Redirect the output of a command with variables to an array

Tags: bash, scripting, array, variable-substitution

I am trying to redirect the output of a command that contains couple of user input variables to an array. I first tried this script -

```
echo "Type the ACL name"
read acl
echo "Type the DATACENTER name"
read dc
echo "ACL is $acl, DC is $dc"
mkdir ~/$acl
device=($(grep -iEr $acl ~/sync-configs/$dc/configs/* | awk -F ':' {'print $1'} | awk -F '/' {'print $NF'} | sort | uniq))
```

The script created the ~/acl directory just fine but the grep did not work for me. Then, after doing some research, I adjusted the grep to put the variables in double quotes, like this -

```
echo "Type the ACL name"
read acl
echo "Type the DATACENTER name"
read dc
echo "ACL is $acl, DC is $dc"
mkdir ~/$acl
device=($(grep -iEr "$acl" ~/sync-configs/"$dc"/configs/* | awk -F ':' {'print $1'} | awk -F '/' {'print $NF'} | sort | uniq))
```

This seems to work fine and I am able to see elements in the device array.

My question is why do I need to put the $acl and $dc quotes when feeding them to the array but the command `mkdir ~/$acl` doesn't require any quotes? Can some one provide clarity on this?

Comment: That would depend on what you enter for `acl` and `dc`, wouldn't it.

Comment: Ah...my acl input is a string. So..that is why i need to escape it with quotes in the grep command? But then, why dont I need to escape it in the mkdir ~/acl command?

Comment: That isn't remotely what I said. _shrug_

Comment: What matters is the *value* you entered at the read prompt, not the type. In a shell there is only one type that is a first class citizen - strings.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells

Comment: @the_velour_fog, well actually, Bash variables can be `declare`d integers too.

Comment: @ilkkachu  thats interesting. a quick scan of man page reveals *If the variable has its integer attribute set, then value is evaluated as an arithmetic expression even if the $((...)) expansion is not used (see Arithmetic Expansion below)*.

Comment: @the_velour_fog, in an assignment, yeah. And in `read`... Which makes for some amusing effects if the value from `read` happens to be the name of a variable. I was going to say something about integer variables being safe from word splitting, but then someone is going to set `IFS=2`, so nevermind.

Comment: @user168115, if the `acl` var contains only a single word, the mkdir works as you expect. Try the same with `acl` set to two words, say `foo bar`.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes I have generally avoided `typeset` and `declare` except which absolutely necessary, e.g. `typeset -A some_array` especially because different shells seem to use them differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking quotes are used to preserve the literal meaning of values and to avoid the interpreter doing transformations on special characters and other operations, such as parameter expansion and word splitting.
If you are using `"` to quote words, variables will be expanded still, but no word splitting will be performed.
Word splitting is the process of the shell taking a string and - conceptually breaking it up into different words, or tokens.
So if you entered this at the read prompt

```
bangalore data center
```

you command would be expanded like so:
With quotes

```
grep -iEr "$acl" ~/sync-configs/"$dc"/configs/*
```

becomes

```
grep -iEr bangalore data center ~/sync-configs/"$dc"/configs/*
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            pattern argument      File/s argument to grep
            to grep
```

Without quotes

```
grep -iEr $acl ~/sync-configs/"$dc"/configs/*
```

becomes

```
grep -iEr bangalore data center ~/sync-configs/"$dc"/configs/*
          ^^^^^^^^^ |^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            pattern |    File/s argument to grep
```

note: in the above `$dc` would have also been expanded.

Comment: For clarity, it might be good to show that `$dc` is also expanded at the same time.